# What's the difference between 'fellow' and 'prig' in connotational meaning?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between 'fellow' and 'prig' in this sentence from *Michael and Mary* (1930) written by A. A. Milne?

> Then tell me: Why are you the devil of a fellow if you like drinking whisky, and the devil of a prig if you don't?

Comment: According to a credible dictionary, what do the words mean?

Comment: Had I been Milne, I'd have written, "Why are you the devil of a prick (i.e., an obnoxiously despicable person) if you like drinking whisky, and the devil of a prig (i.e., an obnoxiously moralistic person) if you don't?"

Comment: Thank you Benjamin Harman for your comment. Your paraphrasing is very explanatory and informative to me.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - you misunderstood the text completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The Devil of a fellow" means *an excellent fellow; a hell of a chap!*

It's old-fashioned slang.

> *We vied with one another in caring for our platoons, and, off duty,
> carried ourselves with no end of swagger, each trying to be the devil
> of a fellow. - A Subaltern's War, Charles Edmonds, 1929*

[The devil of a fellow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20devil%20of%20a%20fellow%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1833,cd_max:1964&lr=lang_en)

[The devil of a chap](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20devil%20of%20a%20chap%22&client=firefox-b-d&biw=1366&bih=694&tbm=bks&ei=p1CGYPWnMOi11fAP-4acgAg&oq=%22The%20devil%20of%20a%20chap%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...29179.30241.0.30937.4.4.0.0.0.0.63.246.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.rFK3WVIa1BY)

*Then tell me: Why are you thought of as a great bloke if you like drinking whisky, and a hell of a prig if you don't?*

Comment: At last! - "The Devil of a fellow" means a great guy; a hell of a chap!

Answer (score 0):

"Fellow " and "prig" are not really related. The relation is through the phrase "The Devil of a...".

"The Devil of a fellow" means "A bad man" (essentially "A devil like man" although it is usually applied to people much less bad than the devil). "The Devil of a prig" means a very bad prig, meaning someone more priggish than an ordinary prig. (A prig being someone who is overly strict in opposing any form of vice or pleasure.)

So a man who likes whiskey is thought to be a bad man, but someone who doesn't is an excessive killjoy.